# Don't fear the wolf

Tags: proverbs

> Fear makes the wolf bigger than he is
>
> — German proverb

What do you need to do to make the wolf look normal sized?

I guess I'm looking for the appropriate word to fill in this sentence:

> ... makes the wolf look the size he actually is

Neither love nor courage seem appropriate which seem to be the standard opposites suggested for fear.

---

**Edit:** replaced "as big as he is" (based on [Max Williams' comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/341918/dont-fear-the-wolf#comment788931_341918), as this could as equally be "as small as" which is not quite what I was thinking of) with "the size he actually is"

Comment: So what exactly would that word or sentence mean? Can you give a short definition of the word you are looking for? I was thinking of "**bravery/dauntlessness/daring**" for instance.

Comment: Something like *"Boldness brings the wolf back down to size"*?

Comment: Your context would give you a chance to employ a standard idiomatic usage almost literally. When you encounter this wolf, what you need to do is [***cut him down to size.***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cut+down+to+size)

Comment: It's worth adding that "look as big as he is" suggests that he was previously looking **not as big**, rather than bigger.  "look as small as he is" would be a better way to put it, for this reason, if you didn't want to use "cut him down to size" or something similar.

Comment: @MorganFR "Daring makes the wolf look as big as he is" doesn't seem to fit. I guess I'm looking for something more along the lines of being logical or accepting the wolf for what he is - trying to take emotion out of it

Comment: **Keeping a cool head** makes the wolf look as big as he is.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I quite like that suggestion - as if you can conquer fear by approaching it like a puzzle that can be solved

Comment: Perhaps the wolf looks big for the same reason my cat does when she's squaring up for a cat fight - their hair stands on end when they're frightened/angry. (So you should talk softly to the wolf, stroke him, and calm him down! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers hmm, perhaps *understanding* would work "understanding makes the wolf look as big as he is", i.e. if you understand the motives of the wolf fear/hunger/parent you can see him more clearly for what he is

Comment: @MaxWilliams you're quite right - small is another way of looking at it. But I just meant 'big' as a term for size. i.e. I was thinking of the accuracy of it rather than trying to make the wolf either bigger or smaller. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the question *per se,* but I can't help myself but remind us all that courage is not the absence of fear, rather thinking straight and taking action despite fear.  Those who have no fear quickly remove themselves from the gene pool.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of [***realism***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/realism) may fit here.

> The attitude or practice of accepting a situation as it is and being prepared to deal with it accordingly:
> *the summit was marked by a new mood of realism*

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/realism

Answer (score 1):

> Fear makes the wolf bigger than he is.
>
> — German proverb

Perhaps something like:

> Confidence keeps the wolf at bay.

Confidence seems the best antonym for fear in this case, though bravery may also apply.

If you are specifically looking to counter the size (though I believe taken together those two sentences would be opposing), you could maybe go with:

> Confidence makes the wolf a wolf.

It doesn't specify a size, but it makes the wolf equal only to itself, not something larger or scarier.